# Obtaining the coefficients and significance of net mobility effects in Diagonal Mobility Models using R's gnm() function

Tags: r, statistics, gnm

How to obtain the net mobility effects in Diagonal Mobility Models (DMM)?

Suppose the model is specified using the `gnm()` function in R.

The baseline DRM model

```
gnm(formula = y ~ -1 + covariates + 
    Dref(origin, destination), data = data)
```

Now add the net mobility effects.

```
gnm(formula = y ~ -1 + covariates + 
    Dref(origin, destination, delta = ~1 + upward + downward), data = data)
```

The output does not specify the coefficients and significance of `upward` and `downward`, which are two binary indicators of upward and downward mobility. Then how to obtain them?

I checked the model outputs by `summary(mod)`.

I checked the weight parameters by `DrefWeights(mod)`

But I did not see a direct output of the net mobility effects of the added terms.